# How do I read values into a structure using pointers?

Tags: c, struct

I know when I have to print I use `p->real` and so on but what should I write when I am reading numbers using `scanf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int real;
    int imaginary;
} complex;

void read(complex*);

void main() {
    complex c;
    read(&c);
}    

void read(complex* p){
    /*what to write in scanf*/
}
```

Comment: Just a question: are you sure your sturcture members should be `int`, not `float` or `double`?

Comment: So I fixed your code's formatting and changed the indentation so it was readable.  It's really helpful to people if you do this when you post your original question...

Comment: @mark- how do i format the code? kindly help.

Comment: Things posted here are formatted with something called Markdown, you can read about the syntax here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Forget `scanf` exists as it usually buys more trouble than it saves by trying to do two tasks (input and parsing) and does both half-way. `fgets` and `sscanf` splits the task and makes parse errors far more easily handled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can write:

```
scanf("%d %d", &p->real, &p->imaginary);
```

but that depends heavily on the format in which the numbers come.

Comment: I would probably say `&(p->real)`, just for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 6):

`scanf` requires you to pass the *address* of the memory space you want to store the result in, unlike `printf`, which only requires the value (it couldn't care less *where* the value resides). To get the address of a variable in C, you use the & operator:

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Meaning: read an integer into the address I specified, in this case the address of a. The same goes for struct members, regardless of whether the struct itself resides on the stack or heap, accessed by pointer, etc:

```
struct some_struct* pointer = ........;
scanf("%d", &pointer->member);
```

And that would read an integer into the address of *pointer* plus the offset of *member* into the structure.

Answer (score -2):

Use Following code:

```
scanf("%d",&pointer->variable);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding a late answer to a question, but this answer adds nothing to the conservation, it's simply a duplicate of the previous two from two years ago. Please add some additional information when answering questions rather than just copping already accepted answers.